# Return different object types in case statement?

Tags: c#, json, object, json.net

How can I return different object types in my case statement?

```
    public object?? CreateObjectType(JToken token)
    {
        switch (token["type"].Value<string>())
        {
            case "Car":
                var Car = new Car();
                return car;

            case "Boat":
                var boat = new Boat();
                return boat;
            ..... 
        }
    }
```

Do I need to create an abstract/interface class to accomplish this? An example of this would be great.

Comment: Can't you define a common base type (eg `Vehicle`) which you derive from, and return that?

Comment: Yes, that is basically polymorphism. Something along the lines of IVehicle maybe

Comment: You'll probably need to create a generic here.

Comment: Thought so, not too familiar with this. I will read into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to tackle this would be to use an interface (in my mind):

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    public class Test
    {
        public IVehicle CreateObjectType(JToken token)
        {
            switch(token["type"].Value<string>())
            {
                case "Car":
                    return new Car();

                case "Boat":
                    return new Boat();

                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Boat : IVehicle { }

    public class Car : IVehicle { }

    public interface IVehicle { }
}
```

Alternatively, you could do some form of inheritance chain and use generics.

Additional: [Documentation on Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/)

Comment: Great thanks, I will read into interfaces more. Can I ask I have a method that already creates Car and populates the necessary properties. Do I simply call on that method and return it e.g. case "Car":
                var Car = CreateMyCar();
                return car; will this work exactly the same? As the method returns the object type

Comment: @Mask-dCodex Yes, you can also just return the method call: `return CreateMyCar();`

Comment: @Mask-dCodex If my answer solved your question, please mark it as such with ✓

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're implementing a basic [factory method pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method):

```
public interface IVehicle {}

public class Car : IVehicle {}
public class Boat : IVehicle {}

public IVehicle CreateObjectType(JToken token)
{
    switch (token["type"].Value<string>())
    {
        case "Car":
            return new Car();
        case "Boat":
            return new Boat();
        default:
          throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(token));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:
`public IVehicle CreateObjectType(JToken token)` 
or 
`public dynamic CreateObjectType(JToken token)`.

remember almost everything `dymanic` take more time to run and to compile.